# Can learning to be Ambidextrous harm Brain Function?

Tags: healthcare, cognitive-science, scientific-papers

I've always read benefits of being (or learning to be) ambidextrous until this Scientific American [article](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/can-training-to-become-ambidextrous-improve-brain-function/) from Michael Corballis that says it is not that helpful and it can even **harm your brain**, as each brain hemisphere has specific tasks to do:

> The two hemispheres of the brain are not interchangeable.

Are there any strong evidence that supports that being ambidextrous can be bad for your health?

Comment: @CelticWarrior this question does not focus in children as the suggested one.